# Looping queries to an API is really slow

Tags: php, json, performance, loops

I've heard that it is possible to loop JSON datas by using only one query and not doing queries for every loop. Any ideas how to make this from this code?
I really need to do it because it takes up to 3 minutes to successfully load the page..

*** PHP ***

```
<?php foreach ($return as $user) {
    $link = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$devkey&steamids=$user->SteamID";
    $json = file_get_contents($link);
    $decoding = json_decode($json);
    $avatar = $decoding->response->players[0]->avatar;
?>
<td id="addme"><img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" width="32" height="32"></td>
<td><?php echo $user->DisplayName; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $user->SteamID; ?>  <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo $user->SteamID; ?>/" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" id="gotosteamprofile"></span></a></td>
<td><?php
         $ipredc = substr($user->Address, 0, -6);
         echo $ipredc; ?></td>
<td><?php 
         $toconver = $user->ConnectedSeconds;
         $hours = floor($toconver / 3600);
         $mins = floor($toconver / 60 % 60);
         $secs = floor($toconver % 60);
         $timeFormat = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
         echo $timeFormat;
      ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: How many users do you want to pull data for?

Comment: Up to 300 players

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to prevent multiple calls to an API is to find a point of synonymous data. Fortunately, Steam provides such a point.

According to the **[Steam API on GetPlayerSummaries](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29)**, you can return data for up to 100 players at the same time. Thus, you should only need to make this call **once** (assuming you're only grabbing data about a few players).

Inside your `foreach ($return as $user)`, you're currently passing `$user` into the query itself:

`&steamids=$user->SteamID`

This acts as a `GET` parameter, and calls the multiple urls:

```
/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$devkey&steamids=12345678
/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$devkey&steamids=23456789
```

This is obviously quite costly, but fortunately, you can pass all of the IDs at once with a `Comma-delimited list of 64 bit Steam IDs to return profile information for`. Thus, you should create this list as a variable to send all at once:

```
$combined_ids = '';
foreach ($return as $user) {
  $combined_ids.= $user->SteamID . ',';
}
// $combined_ids = '1,2,3,4,5';
```

You would then pass this variable into the query, **outside** of a loop:

```
$link = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$devkey&steamids=$combined_ids";
$json = file_get_contents($link);
$decoding = json_decode($json);
```

Finally, **after** the single call to the API, you would do a **secondary** loop through the results for each user, making use of the pre-defined `$decoding` variable.

```
<?php foreach ($return as $user) {

    $avatar = $decoding->response->players[0]->avatar;
    ?>
    <td id="addme"><img src="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" width="32" height="32"></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->DisplayName; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $user->SteamID; ?>  <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<?php echo $user->SteamID; ?>/" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" id="gotosteamprofile"></span></a></td>
    <td><?php
    $ipredc = substr($user->Address, 0, -6);
    echo $ipredc; ?></td>
    <td><?php 
    $toconver = $user->ConnectedSeconds;
    $hours = floor($toconver / 3600);
    $mins = floor($toconver / 60 % 60);
    $secs = floor($toconver % 60);
    $timeFormat = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
    echo $timeFormat;
    ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Note that you might slightly need to tweak the results based on the return from the API processing multiple users at once, rather than one at a time.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I really like the idea. I should have thought of it earlier! I have to retrieve up to 300 players so I guess spliting it into 3 x 100 and doing 3 querries is the way to go!

Comment: Correct :) Just split the loop into three different segments, using three different sets of `$combined_ids` :)

Comment: Working great and definitely decreasing loading time!
Only one thing, it will show the same avatar on every line. I tried increasing the value everytime to retrieve the correct avatar for each steamid but I couldn't make it work

Comment: That would (likely) be coming from `players[0]` in `$avatar`. You'll probably need to use `$user` in place of the zero there :)

Comment: $avatar = $decoding->response->players[$user]->avatar;
Did it, output in HTML is empty

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you can pass comma separated string of max 100 ids.

> Comma-delimited list of 64 bit Steam IDs to return profile information for. Up to 100 Steam IDs can be requested [enter link description here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29)

So based on the answer to my comment, you can do this:

```
$allRows = []; // initialize all rows array

// organize the database result into an array as such
$allSteamUsers = [
    '76561197989628222'=>['Address'=>'Some Address 1','DisplayName'=>'Some Name'], // => some data
    '76561197989628233'=>['Address'=>'Some Address 2','DisplayName'=>'Some Name'], // => some data
    '76561197989628444'=>['Address'=>'Some Address 3','DisplayName'=>'Some Name'], // => some data
    // .......
    '76561197989628447'=>['Address'=>'Some Address 298','DisplayName'=>'Some Name'], // => some data
    '76561197989628448'=>['Address'=>'Some Address 299','DisplayName'=>'Some Name'], // => some data
    '76561197989628449'=>['Address'=>'Some Address 300','DisplayName'=>'Some Name'], // => some data
];

// chunk the user array into parts of 100 and preserve keys
$steamUsersChunks = array_chunk($allSteamUsers, 100, true);

// loop parts
foreach($steamUsersChunks as $steamUsers){

    // build the comma separated id string for the query
    $steam_ids_str = implode(',',array_keys($steamUsers));

    $url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$devkey&steamids=$steam_ids_str";
    $items = json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true); // get JSON and decode with associative array flag set to true
    $players = $items['response']['players']; // get the players array

    $rows = [];

    // loop players array
    foreach($players as $item) {

        // set your variables
        $steamId = $item['steamid'];
        $avatar = $item['avatar'];
        $user_displayName = $steamUsers[$steamId]['DisplayName'];
        $user_Address = $steamUsers[$steamId]['Address'];
        $ipredc = substr($user_Address, 0, -6);

        // build row and add to rows container of this players loop
        $rows[] = '<tr>
        <td id="addme"><img src="'.$avatar.'" width="32" height="32"></td>
        <td>'.$user_displayName.'</td>
        <td>'.$steamId.'  <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$steamId.'/" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" id="gotosteamprofile"></span></a></td>
        <td>'.$ipredc.'</td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>';

    }

    // attach to the general table
    $allRows[] = implode("\n",$rows);

}

// display rows where ever needed
echo implode("\n",$allRows);
```